# The method findViewById(int) is undefined

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to create an application that connects to various social medias (facebook, twitter, etc) and retrieve the unread notifications

In my main activity I have

```
public void retrieveFB(){

    FacebookReceiver fb = new FacebookReceiver();
    fb.loggedInCheck();

}
```

to launch a method to check that the user had login-ed or not, if they do it will just display a facebook logo. But if they don't it will display the loginbutton view for the user to click on

I'm trying to link the fbButtonView to the login_button defined in the xml using

```
fbButtonView = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
```

but it has an error of

> The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type FacebookReceiver

How do I solve this ? Most answer I found in here is to inflate the view in fragment but I'm not sure should I use fragment or not.

Here is my full code

```
public class FacebookReceiver{

TextView fbCount;
LoginButton fbButtonView; //button

public FacebookReceiver()
{
    //constructor
}

public void loggedInCheck(){
    if(isLoggedIn() == null)
    {
        fbButtonView = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);//problem here 
        fbButtonView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   
    }
    else
    {
        String FBCount = null;
        fbCount = (TextView).findViewById(R.id.facebookCount);//here too 

        FBCount = this.getFacebook();
        fbCount.setText(FBCount);
    }
}

private String getFacebook(){
    String FBCount = null;
     try
     {
        FBCount= new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                            "/me/notifications",
                            null,
                            HttpMethod.GET,
                            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                                /* handle the result */
                            }
                        }
                    ).executeAsync().toString();    

     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return FBCount;
}

private AccessToken isLoggedIn(){
    AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    return accessToken ;
}
```

}

Comment: findViewById --->Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that was processed in onCreate(Bundle). You cant use it in a normal class

Comment: Pass context to the constructor and use it with findviewby id like context.findViewById();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, create a `constructor` inside `FacebookReceiver` class like this:

```
private Activity activity;

public FacebookReceiver(Activity activity) 
{ 
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

then from your `MainActivity` class pass activity reference to `FacebookReceiver` class like this:

```
FacebookReceiver fb = new FacebookReceiver(MainActivity.this);
    fb.loggedInCheck();
```

Now update your `loggedInCheck()` method like this:

```
public void loggedInCheck(){ 
    if(isLoggedIn() == null) 
    { 
        fbButtonView = (LoginButton) activity.findViewById(R.id.login_button); 
        fbButtonView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   
    } 
    else 
    { 
        String FBCount = null;
        fbCount = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.facebookCount); 

        FBCount = this.getFacebook();
        fbCount.setText(FBCount);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the FacebookReceiver class does not extend the Activity class, the findViewById method would not be available for this class. If your class is designed to have a user interface so that user can interact with it, it must be an activity or a fragment. Or if it is just used as a background service to check whether user has logged in or not, then it does not have to extend the activity or fragment class.